# How to open facebook messenger from android app

Tags: android

I'm trying to open facebook messenger from my android app. My facebook page's ID `onbiponi`. I've tried the following ways:

> ```
> Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://messaging/onbiponi"));
> startActivity(i);
> ```

another way:

> ```
> Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/onbiponi"));
> startActivity(i);
> ```

But none of the methods are working. How can I open messenger from my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search, I have found the solution:

> ```
> try {
>     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/109002410847188"));
>     startActivity(intent);
> } catch (Exception e) {
>     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.me/onbiponi"));
>     startActivity(intent);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the messenger app by implementing the code below

```java
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://m.me/onbiponi"));
startActivity(i);
```